# How to transform an array into a subset using only jsonpath?

Tags: arrays, json, jsonpath

I'd like to use `jsonpath` to transform an array with 3 elements to just 2 elements.

Given this object:

```
var _base = {
    myArray: [{ item: 1, value: "first" }, { item: 2, value: "second" }, { item: 3, value: "third" }]
}
```

I'd like to use [`jsonpath-object transform`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath-object-transform) to transform the object into:

```
var _newBase = {
    myArray: [{ newItem: 2, newValue: "second" }, { newItem: 3, newValue: "third" }]
}
```

I understand I could do this with a simple `slice` call and some object manipulation, but I have complex, variable objects that I'm transforming at runtime, so `jsonpath` is the requirement.

I'm able to use the below:

```
var transform = require('jsonpath-object-transform');
var template = { ["$.myArray", { "newItem": "$..item", "newValue": "$..value" }] }
transform(_base, _template) //emits the below
```

Which emits:

```
[{ newItem: 1, newValue: "one" }, { newItem: 2, newValue: "second" }, { newItem: 3, newValue: "third" }]
```

But what I really need is the above object without its first index (so just the last two objects in the array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [@path syntax](https://github.com/s3u/JSONPath#syntax-with-examples) to ignore the first item:

```
var _template = {
  foo: ['$.myArray[?(@path !== "$[\'myArray\'][0]")]']
};
```

Returns:

```
{ foo: [ { item: 2, value: 'second' }, { item: 3, value: 'third' } ] }
```

However, it seems that [jsonpath-object transform](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath-object-transform) currently doesn't support mixing both `@path` and accessing subfields like in `{["$.data", {"key": "$.value"}]}`.
So this leaves you with the following options:

- You can acheive what you need by using two transform operations: the first to prune out the first item, and the second to rename subfields.
- `slice`-ing your objects beforehand, as you suggested.
- And finally, patching the library (and submitting a pull request while you're at it!). It's probably a quick fix anyway, shouldn't be too time-consuming.